# Prevent Chatter Recommendations

Tags: chatter, permissions

We are an org of around 60 Enterprise edition users. We have a new user profile (NewProfile) with a few users assigned. I don't want other users to see these NewProfile users as recommendations in Chatter. After looking into [User Sharing](https://eu2.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_sharing_users_tipsheet.pdf) I think that this would solve our problem. Can anyone confirm that by preventing all users from seeing NewProfile users (via public group or role) they would no longer be shown as recommendations to follow in Chatter?